# AngularJS location redirect in AppCtrl, without load the current controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm pretty new to AngularJS,- in my AngularJS app I have a check in my AppCtrl controller if we have to redirect or not.

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    if(window.localStorage.getItem("lastStation")) {
        $location.path('/app/player/'+window.localStorage.getItem("lastStation"));
    }
    ....

.controller('PlayerCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    alert($stateParams); // This one is alerted TWICE if the $location.path is called in the AppCtrl controller
```

Hope someone can help with that! ;)

Comment: Please fix your typos. The question is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You must have configured routing for your application, like:

```
yourApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/app/player/:lastLocation', {
        templateUrl: 'path_to_your_view',
        controller: 'PlayerCtrl'
      }).
      .....
  }]);
```

Comment: Arhh, sorry, I already have done that.., that works all fine!

Answer (score 0):

Now I got it ;)

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    if(window.localStorage.getItem("lastStation")) {
        $location.path('/app/player/'+window.localStorage.getItem("lastStation"));
    }
});
```

I had to make the check in a .run method.